# I am getting NPE while stubbing the method using Junit5 and Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class dmeoStatusServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    DemoService demoService;

    @Mock
    DemoRepository demoRepository;

    @Test
    public void shouldDetailedStatus() {
        Optional<Tenant> tenantOptional = Optional.of(createTenantMockObject());
        when(demoRepository.findByMtuNumber("MTU2")).thenReturn(tenantOptional);
    
        demoService.detailedStatus("Deep Shah", "MTU2");

        verify(demoRepository, times(1)).findByMtuNumber("MTU2");
       }
    }
```

Comment: DemoService is null?(!)

Comment: @xerx593 yes....

Comment: Have you considered assigning an object to demoService so that it is not null? "@InjectMocks DemoService demoService = new DemoService();"

Comment: @Torben No I haven't tried but Isn't MockitoExtension takes care of that??An also the service's constructor is protected

Comment: You need to create an actual `demoService` to use as your "System Under Test". The `@InjectMocks` annotation will inject the demoRepository into your demoService, but it won't create a demoService for you.

Comment: @k314159 Everything was working perfectly when I tried with Junit4 and MockitoJunitRunner the problem starts after I migrate to junit5 and mockitoExtension...

Comment: ..or use "normal" sprinboottest (annotation) + `@Autowired` (for s.u.t.) and `@mockbean` for mocks.

Comment: @xerx593 Not helping

Comment: I tried your test and don't see NullPointerException, can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: @k314159 that is not true. `@InjectMocks` creates the testing object. See [Mockito Docs](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you are using Junit 5 @Test annotation

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

// not

import org.junit.Test;
```

Comment: I am importing it from junit5 only..

Comment: @DeepShah are you sure? No sub dependencies of JUnit4?

Comment: Maybe paste in the full class showing imports

Comment: @akop what do you mean by  sub-dependencies of Junit4?

Comment: @DeepShah did you have any other dependencies which importing JUnit4? Just check if the import-statement in your test is correct like johnnynutts described.